# Why this SVG has half of its outline missing in both Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, firefox, inkscape

This is an SVG which has a complete outline (the black border) in Inkscape, but it is not the case in Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="7 4.5 7.5 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" overflow="visible" transform="" style="position: absolute;">
   <defs>
   <path id="main0" d="M9.517312453695235 5.581015952966315 L8.563199389605689 6.6027522826740395 L9.517312453695235 5.581015952966315"></path>
   <mask id="mask/main0" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <use xlink:href="#main0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1.625" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></use>
       <use xlink:href="#main0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.55" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></use>
   </mask>
   </defs>
   <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#main0" opacity="0.2" fill="#ff50c0" stroke="#ff50c0" stroke-width="1.55" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></use>
   <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#main0" opacity="0.7" fill="transparent" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.625" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" mask="url(#mask/main0)"></use>
</svg>
```

Here are the renderings:[image]

Increasing the view box' width restores the full outline. Decreasing that width makes the outline disappear completely. Why is it the case? Can it be corrected, so that there is always a full outline? By corrected, I do not mean defining directly a rounded path, but leaving the method of drawing mostly as it is, i.e. a polygon with an outset. I need it like that for a smooth in-browser animation. Drawing an opaque black filled polygon and then filling it with another, smaller polygon wont't work as well, as I need a semi-transparent fill but opaque border. Thus the use of a mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask simply isn't big enough to cover the shape. You've not set any height/width for it so you'll get the defaults of 120%. That's not enough in this case for the width.

Increasing the viewBox width corrects things as the mask width is a percentage of that viewBox width so you're indirectly increasing the mask width.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="7 4.5 7.5 10" preserveAspectRatio="none" overflow="visible" transform="" style="position: absolute;">
   <defs>
   <path id="main0" d="M9.517312453695235 5.581015952966315 L8.563199389605689 6.6027522826740395 L9.517312453695235 5.581015952966315"></path>
   <mask id="mask/main0" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="150%">
       <use xlink:href="#main0" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1.625" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></use>
       <use xlink:href="#main0" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.55" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></use>
   </mask>
   </defs>
   <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#main0" opacity="0.2" fill="#ff50c0" stroke="#ff50c0" stroke-width="1.55" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></use>
   <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#main0" opacity="0.7" fill="transparent" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.625" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" mask="url(#mask/main0)"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there any method of computing a minimal mask? In the case of this image the minimal mask seems to be about (11, 10) which I cannot explain, given that the viewport is (7.5, 10). I decreased the view box to improve performance, the rendering speed is critical here. I would not want a slower rendering because of an unnecessarily large mask.

Comment: Is the mask always centered around the view box, independently of the sizes of both? I cannot find anything about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask

Comment: A better (separate) question would be why you're trying to do this in this complicated way. You've not explained the animation in detail. Maybe you can do it without a mask at all.

Comment: Where the mask is depends on its position (x, y, width, height) or the defaults if you don't specify them. Those attributes and their defaults are described in the MDN article you linked to.

Comment: So in this case, an optimal mask would simply be one which fits the viewport: x="7" y="4.5" width="7.5" height="10". Thanks!